# numpy memory error when loading images

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I wanted to load a huge dataset of images in numpy array to make it as a training data for the cnn model I am trying to train. It is giving me memory error when I try to create a numpy array as below.
`np.ndarray(shape=(250000, 3, 512, 512))` 
How else can I load such a huge dataset in python?

Comment: Try using `dtype=np.uint8`. This is as low as you can go for RGB images.

Comment: It doesn't work either

Comment: Well, if you don't have ~24GB RAM for numpy you won't be able to load 1/4mio. images.

Comment: Is there any other way to load 1 million data other than using numpy?

Comment: You just CAN'T load that much at once if you don't have the according PC specs.

Comment: Construct a generator, which outputs the number of images you are using in a single batch. Call the fit() method whilst looping through the generator. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Please tell us which machine learning framework are you using (e.g. Keras, Tensorflow, Pytorch). Depending on the framework there are several ways to avoid load the whole dataset on the RAM (which for huge datasets is impossible)

---

In this case, you could use fit_generator function of Keras. This will allow you to load your images into batches instead of loading the full dataset in the RAM. Your generator can be any python function, but probably in your case an [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) with flow_from_directory method will fulfill.

Take a look to the following examples:

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly.html

Comment: Posting comments as answers doesn't get you comment permissions any faster.

Comment: I am using keras on top of theano frameowork. I need to load the dataset to train a CNN regression model